# Turn ordered List A & List B to Ordered List C

Tags: java, java-stream

Here the problem I am having :

I have :

- a List<String> names; provided by my GUI where the order is significative;
- a List<CustomObject> customObjects; where customObject could have the same "name" attribut.

I need to return a List<CustomObject> customObjects; composed of one element for a name (any of them) with the same order than names.

I tried some things but I feel it has to nest a for with a stream and I think I'll have to do otherwise.

For exemple :

```
    Map<String, CustomObjects> map = customObjects.stream().filter(co -> names.contains(co.getName())).collect(Collectors.toMap(CustomObjects::getName, co->co));

for(String name : names) {
  customObjetsToReturn.add(map.get(name));
}
```

Or

```
    for (String name : names) {
  customObjects.stream().filter(co -> name.equals(co.getName())).findFirst().ifPresent(customObjectsToReturn::add);
}
```

Comment: Any code snippet that you have tried would be useful to provide suggestions.

Comment: What is `CustomObject` and how expect a string to be converted into it? Show us your code.

Comment: `order is significative` - What do you mean by that? Initial order must be preserved?

Comment: Yes @AlexanderIvanchenko, the order have to be preserved, thanks

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking about? How is the `names` list connected to the `customObjects` list What do you mean by _**composed of one element for a name (any of them) with the same order than names**_ ? Can you give a sample input and the expected output? If for example your names list contains the strings `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` how coluld a sample custom objects list look like and what do you want returned?

Comment: names could be like : ["foo","bar","baz"]
customObjects could be like (i just print the name in this array for simplification): ["foo","fii","bar","baz","foo","toto","bar","baz","foo","bar","baz"]
I need a customObject list like : ["foo","bar","baz"]

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the resulting list by applying `Collectors.toList()` in the stream without creating a *loop*.

---

**Update**

> I need to return a customObjectList where it size is the same of the
> inital nameList
>
> customObjects have **several** items who have the same name

If I understood your intention correctly, the resulting list needs to be based on the values from the list of names.

The code below will be useful only if there's a particular rule on how to choose the object from the group of duplicates, it needs to be added as the third argument of the `Collectors.toMap()` (*now it chooses the first encountered*).

```
Map<String, CustomObjet> objByName =
            customObjects.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(CustomObject::getName, 
                                                Function.identity()),
                                                (v1, v2) -> v1); // rule on how to dial with duplicates (when name is the same)

    List<CustomObjet> customObjetsToReturn =
            names.stream()
                    .filter(objByName::containsKey)
                    .map(objByName::get)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I cant because, customObjects have several items who have the same name and i need to keep only one element by name (any of them)

Comment: I need to return a customObjectList where it size is the same of the inital nameList

Comment: @Mathieu You need to add this requirement to the question. And it's not clear how from your code how you want to insure the size of the resulting list.

Comment: @Mathieu List of objects could be both smaller o greater than list of item. You have to give clear instructions for these cases.

Comment: @Mathieu I've updated the code. `customObjects have several items who have the same name` - if there could be more than one object with the same name, is there any rule which one to choose or any will do?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to filter all `CustomObject` whose name appear in the `names` list and then you want to have distinct `CustomObject`s by the attribute `name`. If so something like below should do the trick:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

....


List<String> names; //your names
List<CustomObject> customObjects; //your objs

List<CustomObject> filterd =
            customObjects.stream()
                         .filter(co -> names.contains(co.getName()))
                         .filter(distinctByKey(CustomObject::getName))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());

public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```